# Fallo en build github page

Tags: github-pages, github-actions

Buenas estoy creando un blog con github pages pero ala hora de hacer el build me esta dando este error:

```
Run bundle exec htmlproofer _site --disable-external --check-html --allow_hash_href
Running ["ScriptCheck", "LinkCheck", "ImageCheck", "HtmlCheck"] on ["_site"] on *.html... 


- _site/posts/ejpt/index.html
Ran on 13 files!
  *  internally linking to ..\assets\ejpt.jpg, which does not exist (line 1)
     <a href="..\assets\ejpt.jpg" class="popup img-link "><img data-src="..\assets\ejpt.jpg" alt="eJPT" class="lazyload" data-proofer-ignore=""></a>


HTML-Proofer found 1 failure!

Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Entiendo que es porque no encuentra la imagen, sin embargo en el post que hace referencia la imagen esta es la ruta que puse

```
![eJPT](..\assets\ejpt.jpg)
```

En el VS al hacer control+click puedo ver la imagen correctamente asi que nose a que se debe este error. ¿Alguna idea?

Gracias de antemano.